# how to make arduino as mind thought reader?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I'm trying to create arduino base mind reader... And for that I thought that EEG electrode connected to arduino and then the data send to arduino in 01 form .. But I facing problem in how to convert this or which wave (alpha, beta,delta)give very high or acutrate result.

Answer (score 5):

Even if the answer provided by Mike is really doable and can be implemented you should really think about what you want to reach and what is your goal.

The big difference between EEG and mind readers is that the process of thinking, even if you can record all that waves: alpha, gamma,... can be never decoded to get useful informations. I mean: you can record and get a confirm that you have more gamma waves when you are doing meditation. Or that aplha and beta wave are going to be much more present when waking up or in particular hours of the days, but you never get an image of what the person is thinking or what are its emotions... That because you can get some waves coming from the brain but you cannot reconstruct the billion of processes that are happening *inside* the brain.

A lot of researcher are trying to decoder those informations to move as an example an arm or a leg. But it is the front edge of the reasearch really not doable with an Arduino....

Anyway good luck!

Comment: And to add to that - the cheap way of getting alpha/beta/gamma etc. is VERY unreliable. A real EEG would have several dozens of electrodes connected directly to the head's skin, as oppose to a single metal functioning as a voltage detector, that needs to handle too much noise.

Answer (score 3):

You could hack an existing device like the Mattel Mind Flex ($20-50 on Ebay).

There have been a number of projects that do exactly what you have described - there's even an arduino library: https://github.com/kitschpatrol/Brain

http://frontiernerds.com/brain-hack